# How can i show Div or Panel Over iFrame

Tags: asp.net, css

how can i show panel over iframe. I have tried using z-Index but its not working check out the sample image. We'll I didn't tried using css i use Z-Index but it is not working. 
Below is my code...

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%"><tr align="left"><td align="left"><iframe width="70%" frameborder="0" height="770" id="myframe" runat="server" src="about:blank"></iframe></td></tr></table>
<div class="slide-out-div"><a class="handle" href="http://link-for-non-js-users">Content</a><h3 class="style1">Menu Items</h3><table border="0">
        <tr style=" float:left; height:39px"><td><ul><li><a href="">Special Instructions</a></li></ul></td></tr>
        <tr style=" float:left; height:39px"><td><ul><li><a href="">Processing Exception</a></li></ul></td></tr>
        <tr style=" float:left; height:39px"><td><ul><li><a href="">Account Coding</a></li></ul></td></tr>
        <tr style=" float:left; height:39px"><td><ul><li><a href="">View My Notes</a></li></ul></td></tr>
        <tr style=" float:left; height:39px"><td><ul><li><a href="">Approve/Disapprove</a></li></ul></td></tr>
        <tr style=" float:left; height:39px"><td><ul><li><a href="">Save & Close</a></li></ul></td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `position:absolute` CSS styling?

Comment: can you show me give me sample code for that...

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far? (http://whathaveyoutried.com) We're not a code writing service

Comment: Is it happening in all browsers?  For IE, I did a trick of using an empty iframe behind a calendar popup to allow it to show on top of other windowed elements.

Comment: Make sure the both elements have their 'position' css attributes set to something other than static (which they are by default.

Comment: Agree with above.  Without seeing your code I have no way of knowing, but my guess is that one of the elements doesn't have a position attribute set.

Comment: We'll I didn't tried using css i use Z-Index but it is not working. I have updated my post with my code.

Comment: The screenshot looks like you've got a PDF being displayed by Acrobat's browser plugin. Plugins can interfere with the rendering order of the page. What happens if you replace the PDF view with regular HTML?

Comment: yes.. its by default using acrobat browser plugin what do you mean by replace pdf view with regular html ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should look at using the `position:absolute` CSS styling.

Here is an example...

```
<div id="straddle">
    Here is the straddling div<br/>
    Here is the straddling div
</div>
<iframe id="myframe" src="about:blank"></iframe>
```

With the following example CSS...

```
#myframe {
    height:100px;
    width:200px;
    margin-left:100px;
}
#straddle {
    position:absolute;
    width:200px;
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

Please see [this jsfiddle live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RRUUQ/1/)

Comment: Hey FreeFaller... Thanks for your help.

Comment: You're welcome @Rick, thanks for the mark :-) Hope you got your project working

Comment: Yes... Hello FreeFaller i have 1 more query will u please give me some suggestion over that here is the link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11607893/hide-the-iframe-under-panel-div-object/11608267#11608267

Comment: I would also add `background-color: rgba(100,100,100,1);` to #straddle and `z-index` to both css sections.