# Hide the iFrame Under Panel / Div Object

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css

As you can see in my image I have Pdf (Which is in the iFrame) along with a Jquery Sliding Menu (Which is in the Div/Panel) along with another iFrame.. I want to hide Sliding Menu iFrame (The reason for adding Panel Under iframe because as pdf viewer behaviour panel will hide itself under Pdf and will not be visible on the form). For that I tried setting display attribute = none; which not worked :( Is there any way to hide the iFrame but the Panel should be at its place.

[image]

Comment: your question is not particular clear, but from what I think you're saying: you want the HTML being displayed within the "menu" iFrame to stay visible when you make the iFrame invisible? Can you confirm this, or try and make your question clearer

Comment: Also, it's confusing when you say things are "under" an iframe - when what I *think* you mean is they are **in** an iframe (remember, an iframe is simply a container for displaying a separate HTML document, PDF file, etc).  Unless you really are talking about items that are behind the iframe?

Answer (score 0):

Use firebug to detect if you are getting element in watch expression or not..you should access iFrame like this

```
<form name="formname" .... id="form-first">
<iframe id="one" src="iframe2.html">
</iframe>
</form>


function iframeRef( frameRef ) {
return frameRef.contentWindow ? frameRef.contentWindow.document : frameRef.contentDocument
}

var inside = iframeRef( document.getElementById('one') )
```

Comment: Hello Mayank Pathak.. I Think u didn't understand my question what i said is that I want to hide the iFrame which is beneath the Menu Control Panel... So How can i do that.. ?

Comment: see above code..you have got the iFrame in inside variable..not apply attribute on this variable to hide iFrame...